# How to get values from database loop and add them up for later use

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I am querying the database for different values of prizes for an online loyalty scheme.

I know this is going to be a sort of easy question but Im still getting used to PHP so here goes...

This is what I have so far:

```
 <?php $sqlprize="SELECT prizeid FROM wp_scloyalty_orders WHERE  userid = '$user_id'";

            $resultprize=mysql_query($sqlprize); ?>

            <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultprize)){  

                    query_posts('post_type=prizes&showposts=-1&p='.$rows['prizeid'].''); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);


                        //echo $my_meta['pointsvalue'];

                    endwhile; 
                    wp_reset_query();  



             } ?>
```

Basically I want it so each time it loops the database query it adds the value (my_meta['pointsvalue'] to an array, which I can use outside of the loop...

Thanks!

EDIT-----------------

```
               <?php $purchasevalue=array(); ?>

           <?php $sqlprize="SELECT prizeid FROM wp_scloyalty_orders WHERE  userid = '$user_id'";

            $resultprize=mysql_query($sqlprize); ?>

            <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultprize)){  

                    query_posts('post_type=prizes&showposts=-1&p='.$rows['prizeid'].''); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);            

                        $purchasevalue[] = $my_meta['pointsvalue'];         
                    endwhile; 
                    wp_reset_query();  

             } ?>

             <?php echo array_sum($purchasevalue) ?>
```

Thanks guys, sorted it in the end... is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: Are you planning on referring to the derived value within the scope of the code snippet, or anywhere from your application?

Comment: Anywhere in the application really, using it to subtract from a value of how many points each user has left in their account. Think I sorted it... it works anyway, is that a good way of approacing it u think?

Comment: If I were you, I would add this value as a member to a user account object, so when they log in, you calculate the amount, then set the value via the user account object. Then you can retrieve it like `$user->getPointsValue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_push to add values to an array

```
$array = array();

while()....
   $my_meta = ....
   array_push($array, $my_meta);
end while;

//Your array is now
print_r($array);
```

Hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, yeah that would have done it, but before I read this I think Ive sorted it myself. That ok u think?